Estimation of $\lvert\arg (z)-\arg(u)\rvert$
Let $z,u\in \mathbb{C}$ such that
$$|\arg z|<\theta_{1}~~~,~~~|\arg u|<\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\theta_{2}~~~\text{where}~~~0<\theta_{1}<\dfrac{\pi}{2},0<\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\theta_{2}<\dfrac{\pi}{2}$$
Such that $\theta_{1}<\theta_{2}$.
Then I need estimation of
$$|\arg (z)-\arg(u)|$$
I know that
$$|\arg (z)-\arg(u)|<\theta_{1}+\theta_{2}$$
But my teacher need a good estimation
He say the estimation is like that
$$|\arg (z)-\arg(u)|<\theta_{2}-\theta _{1}$$
But I don't know how prove it
I think the estimation is
$$|\arg (z)-\arg(u)|<\big|\theta_{2}-\theta _{1}\big|$$

This doesn't seem to be about complex numbers at all. If $a$ and $b$ are real, and $|a|<\theta_1$ and $|b|<\theta_2$, then the best inequality one can get on $|a-b|$ is $|a-b| < \theta_1+\theta_2$ (since $a$ could be very close to $\theta_1$ and $b$ could be very close to $-\theta_2$).
